# MySQL ego command in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Is there something like the MySQL ego command available in Oracle sqlplus or sql script that do the same thing? MySQL ego command displays query results vertically in MySQL command line console.

Output from mysql console looks like:

```
mysql> select * from actor \G;

*************************** 1. row ***************************

   actor_id: 1                                                
 first_name: PENELOPE                                         
  last_name: GUINESS                                          
last_update: 2006-02-15 04:34:33


*************************** 2. row ***************************

   actor_id: 2                                                
 first_name: NICK                                             
  last_name: WAHLBERG                                         
last_update: 2006-02-15 04:34:33


*************************** 3. row ***************************

   actor_id: 3                                                
 first_name: ED                                               
  last_name: CHASE                                            
last_update: 2006-02-15 04:34:33
```

Comment: If you are talking about Oracle's SQL*Plus program, the *mysql* tag is misguiding. Try to explain what you want to accomplish so Oracle users who are not proficient with MySQL have a chance to answer.

Comment: tnx for response, I am talking about Oracle's SQL Plus, i am trying to produce output similar to the above

Answer (score 2):

Try the `print_table` function described here:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1035431863958

Answer (score 1):

Try to finish your query in mysql console whith \G instead of ;